Gen 2 Amplify accessing User Attributes
To access user attributes like: name and family_name, that were given during the signup phase of a user's account in amplify using the authenticator that is provided, how do we access it?
While checking the cognito user pool on the aws site, it does show that the name and family name, and userId and user email are all there, yet in the code I am only able to access:
user.username,
user.userId
user.username is the cognito id of the user
and the user.signInDetails.loginId is the user's email
Here is some code.
My hope is just to be able to put user.name and user.family_name and get the result back but that didn't work...
return (
    <Authenticator signUpAttributes={[
      'name', 
      'family_name', 
      'phone_number',
      ]}>
      {({ signOut, user }) => (
        <main>
          <h1>Hello {user?.username}</h1>
          <h1>{user?.signInDetails?.loginId}'s files</h1>
        </main>
      )}
    </Authenticator>
  );


You'll need to call fetchUserAttributes.
There isn't much detail in the docs, but here is a link: Retrieve user attributes
It will look something like this:
import { fetchUserAttributes } from 'aws-amplify/auth';

//...

let name, family_name, phone_number;

try {
  attributes = await fetchUserAttributes();
  name = attributes.name;
  family_name = attributes.family_name;
  phone_number = attributes.phone_number;
} catch (err) {
  // console.error(err);
  // ... handle error ...
}

